# Javascript confirm box not able to submit form on selecting yes

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

In jsp , clicking on button called `sumbitForm()` function as below

```
document.Data.formSubmit.value="Yes";
document.Data.action.value='SUMBIT';
document.Data.submit();
```

here giving proper result and setting value as occured on controller

In same JSP, calling  `onload` function ,In that checking if command class variable set =  occured then only confirmation box can show and after clicking yes button of confirmation box then  request should process.. I used `document.Data.submit()` but its not working and not giving exception.

Comment: make fiddle, or make sure your confirm box return true when you select yes. other thing is simple as true false.

Comment: Avoid using attribute names `action` for input elements

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form ") == true ){
        // then submit the form
    }

Comment: I am using custom pop up and if block executing if i giving alert.only thing document.Data.submit(); not happening from confirmation box